# WPF element property binding

Tags: wpf, binding

I'v got two drop down lists. When selectedIndex for both of these is not -1 it should enable a button. How element property binding can be used here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a MultiBinding to bind the IsEnabled property of the Button to multiple SelectedIndex properties, and then you need an IMultiValueConverter to convert the numbers to a Boolean. Here is a great example: http://www.developingfor.net/wpf/multibinding-in-wpf.html

Comment: Oh, and I hope you're really doing WPF, not Silverlight, because MultiBinding is not supported in Silverlight, although several people have rolled there own (for example: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/(

Answer (score 2):

MultiBindings and MultiValueConverters work well, but my first advice to you would be to use M-V-VM. If you are using [M-V-VM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) then you would simply tie the button enabling to a [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) or to a property on your ViewModel such as `IsActionAvaialable`. I find that using M-V-VM results in me needing much fewer ValueConverters (just my 2 cents).